# Update values of a table with the element of the same row on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, ssms

I've got a table A with a number of rows, and a function returning a table B with only a single row. I need to update each value of A.Other and A.ID with the standard value returned by the function in B, so from:

```
---------- TABLE A ---------      ------------ TABLE B ------------
id     Name   ID   Other        Def_Other   Def_Province   Def_ID 
1        x    1    asqas         hello        PD            0
2        y    10   asd
3        Z    12   adf
```

Table A should become:

```
---------- TABLE A --------- 
id     Name   ID   Other     
1        x     0   hello    
2        y     0   hello
3        Z     0   hello
```

I've tried by

```
update dbo.Table_A 
set Other = select top 1 name FROM dbo.generate_table_b(1)
```

but couldn't do it. 
It it possible to do it without declaring a variable for each column\type? I'd have to edit a number of fields with different types.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
update a
    set Other = b.name,
        id = b.Def_ID 
    from dbo.Table_A a cross join
         dbo.generate_table_b(1) b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
UPDATE a
      set a.id = b.Def_ID,
          a.Other = b.Def_Other 
FROM tablea a CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT b.*
      FROM dbo.generate_table_b(1)
     ) b;
```